# Pass dynamically created multiprocess.Event() through a process Queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I just started getting familiar with multiprocessing in python and got stuck at a problem which I'm not able to solve the way i want and I don't find any clear information if what I'm trying is even properly solvable.

What i'm trying to do is something similar to the following:

```
import time

from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Queue
from threading import Thread

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task_queue = Queue()

        self.process = MyProcess(self.task_queue)
        self.process.start()

    def execute_script(self, code):
        ProcessCommunication(code, self.task_queue).start()


class ProcessCommunication(Thread):
    def __init__(self, script, task_queue):
        super().__init__()

        self.script = script
        self.script_queue = task_queue

        self.script_end_event = Event()

    def run(self):
        self.script_queue.put((self.script, self.script_end_event))

        while not self.script_end_event.is_set():
            time.sleep(0.1)


class MyProcess(Process):
    class ExecutionThread(Thread):
        def __init__(self, code, end_event):
            super().__init__()
            self.code = code
            self.event = end_event

        def run(self):
            exec(compile(self.code, '<string>', 'exec'))
            self.event.set()

    def __init__(self, task_queue):

        super().__init__(name="TEST_PROCESS")

        self.task_queue = task_queue

        self.status = None

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if not self.task_queue.empty():
                script, end_event = self.task_queue.get()
                if script is None:
                    break

                self.ExecutionThread(script, end_event).start()
```

So I would like to have one separate process, which is running during the whole runtime of my main Process, to execute user written scripts in an environment with restriced user privileges, restriced namespace. Also to protect the main process from potential endless loops without waiting times which load the CPU core too much.

Example Code to use the structure could look something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     main_class = Main()

     main_class.execute_script("print(1)")
```

The main process can start several scripts simultaneously and I would like to pass an event, together with the execution request, to the process so that the main process gets notified whenever one of the scripts finished.

However, the Python process Queues somehow do not like the passing of events thorugh the queue and throw the following Error.

```
'RuntimeError: Semaphore objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance'
```

As I create another event with every execution request, I can't pass them on instantiation of the Process.

I came up with one way to solve this, which is passing an identifier together with the code and basically set up another queue which is served with the identifier whenever the end_event would be set. However, the usage of events seems much more elegant to me and i wonder if there is solution which I did not think of yet.

Comment: What leads to the need of creating a new Event per every execution request?

Comment: The fact that several scripts can be started simultaneously. Therefore with one event, the Main Process can not distinguish which script finished.

Comment: How are the scripts started? With `subprocess`?

Comment: The process is once started in the beginning (init function of class "Main") and runs for the remainder of the program. New script are then passed through a process queue and a thread is started within the process for each script, which run as long as the script runs.

The reason why the scripts all run in the same process and I don't just spawn a process for every script is, that they also need to share variables between each other and I don't want to have another queue to do that.